# AWK : parsing output of multiple commands

Tags: shell, unix, awk

Below is my script that I am using to grep all errors / exceptions from my application logs:

```
$ tail -f -n 0 /web/*/logs/*.log | awk '{ if ( $0 ~ /==>.*<==/) { print "File :" $0 } else if( $0 ~ /error/ || $0 ~ /Error/ || $0 ~ /exception/ || $0 ~ /Excpetion/ || $0 ~ /ORA-/ || $0 ~ /fatal/ || $0 ~ /Fatal/){print "Error " $0}}'
```

The output comes out fine but my requirement is that I need to parse output of other system commands parallely like:

```
vmstat
top 
sar
```

etc.

Is there a way that via running a single awk command I can get output of all the command something like:

```
awk process output of:

application logs
vmstat
top 
sar
```

etc

Please note that we have awk and gawk only installed in our boxes.

Comment: I'm not sure tailing 'top' will be a good idea. It's not really built for this and dumps lots of control characters to its output stream

Comment: Well actually I meant that awk { 'tail of app logs ' ==> 'process'; 'output of vmstat' ==> 'process'} etc. I mean that awk program calls multiple system commands and there are multiple blocks in awk program to process each system command output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way using `GNU awk`. Run like:

```
awk -f script.awk
```

Contents of `awk.script`:

```
BEGIN {
    printf "Process output of:\n"

    command0="tail -f -n 0 /web/*/logs/*.log"
    command1="vmstat"
    command2="free"
    command3="ps -eo pcpu,pid,user,tty,args"

    printf "\n>%s:\n\n", command0
    while ( (command0 |& getline var0) > 0) {
        if (var0 ~ /==>.*<==/) {
            print "File :" var0
        }
        else if (var0 ~ /[Ee]rror|[Ee]xception|ORA|[Ff]atal/) {
            print "Error", var0
        }
    }

    printf "\n>%s:\n\n", command1
    while ( (command1 |& getline var1) > 0) {
        print var1
    }

    printf "\n>%s:\n\n", command2
    while ( (command2 |& getline var2) > 0) {
        print var2
    }

    printf "\n>%s:\n\n", command3
    while ( (command3 |& getline var3) > 0) {
        print var3
    }
}
```

As you can see, this script will run four commands, `tail`, `vmstat`, `free` and `ps`. Now the onus is on you to do something with var[1-3]. Please let me know if I can help further. Goodluck.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the example - it helped me a lot. There is only one issue - tail -f options means to follow the file for any appended lines - so when command tail with -f options starts it goes for ever and other options does not gets executed

Comment: @Prakash: Ahh yes, `tail -f` would give you problems. I simply copy/pasted the command and directory. I guess you could always move the `tail` command behind the others, so that it is executed last. Just an idea depending on what you want to do. Cheers.